# implement InputMappedClassifier weka to java

Tags: java, weka

i've tryng to add InputMappedClassifier from weka to java code. Because there my data Train and Test are not compatible. Can someone give me an advice how to add that before I can use the modelfor other classifier?

There my code

```
InputMappedClassifier mapped = new InputMappedClassifier();
        mapped.buildClassifier(Training);
        Instances mappedClassifierDataset = mapped.getModelHeader(Training);
        for (int i = 0; i < Training.numInstances(); i++) {
            Instance map = mapped.constructMappedInstance(Training.instance(i));
            mappedClassifierDataset.add(map);
        }
        System.out.println(mappedClassifierDataset);

        Classifier classifier = new NaiveBayes();
        classifier.buildClassifier(Training);
        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(Testing);
        eval.evaluateModel(classifier, Testing);
        evalResut = eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", false);
```

Comment: How do you create testing and training set. Show the code.

Comment: sorry but my code for create the data is too long

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to use the InputMappedClassifier only because the train and test datasets are incompatible. But *how much incompatible* are these datasets? 
The following code works if your test-datest features are a superset of the training dataset features (all the features in train exist also in test plus other features)

```
InputMappedClassifier mappedCls = new InputMappedClassifier();
    cls.buildClassifier(data);
    mappedCls.setModelHeader(data);
    mappedCls.setClassifier(cls);
    mappedCls.setSuppressMappingReport(true);
    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(testdata);
    eval.evaluateModel(mappedCls, testdata);
```

If the train dataset contains features that are not present in the test dataset you have to apply also the opposite before you evaluate the model.

Hope it helps.

Comment: is different contain feature you mean is like this?
**train** attribute 1(a,b,c) and **test** attribute 1(a,c). If so how to apply the opposite for test data. Sorry i'm newbie for this

Comment: Hello Lefteris, can I get your answer about apply to opposite data?
I need your help, Thanks